# Cannot see existing web-to-lead form for System admin user

Tags: web2lead

I am able to create web to lead forms but can't see existing forms to edit them. The default lead creator or someone else, si that the problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really old feature of SFDC (early 2000's) designed to generate HTML to insert into your web page. IF you need to edit, you can't. You have to regenerate.

Thus, it is worth looking at the current web page to see what fields were generated so you don't forget them. Best practice would be to version control the generated HTML (or even a screen shot of the configuration form) so you can avoid missing something when editing

Of course, you can directly edit the web page and add new fields. Custom fields use their Field Ids, standard fields have English names

Comment: Thanks, what is the latest feature to generate web2lead?

Comment: I know a lot of my clients have moved to marketing automation systems like Hubspot to host the lead capture forms and then use automation to "marketing qualify" the leads before syncing them to SFDC Lead object